# repeating a section of a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I'm having to parse a text dump of a spreadsheet.  I have a regular expression that correctly parses each line of the data, but it's rather long.  It's basically just matching a certain pattern 12 or 13 times.

The pattern I want to repeat is

```
\s+(\w*\.*\w*);
```

This is the regular expression (shortened)

```
^\s+(\w*\.*\w*);\s+(\w*\.*\w*);\s+(\w*\.*\w*);\s+(\w*\.*\w*);\s+(\w*\.*\w*);\s+(\w*\.*\w*);
```

Is there a way to match a pattern a set number of times without copy pasting like this?  Each of those sections correspond to data columns, all of which I need.  I'm using Python by the way.  Thanks!

Comment: Time to change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using:

```
[x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'(\s+(\w*\.*\w*);)*', text)]
```

Did you find the `findall` method yet? Or consider splitting at `;`?

```
map(lambda x: x.strip(), s.split(";"))
```

is probably what you *really* want.

Comment: Ah, that's a great idea.  Splitting at semicolon is much simpler.  All I would need to do is remove the whitespace.  Thanks!

Answer (score 69):

`(\s+(\w*\.*\w*);){12}`

The `{n}` is a "repeat n times"

if you want "12 - 13" times,

`(\s+(\w*\.*\w*);){12,13}`

if you want "12+" times,

`(\s+(\w*\.*\w*);){12,}`

Comment: ... so `(...){12}` repeats the enclosed pattern `...` 12 times; just added this to save you the comparison of the (rather long) pattern with the original question.

Comment: how about infinity?