# Split csv with regex pattern (repetition?)

Tags: python, regex, csv, split

I'm new in RegEx and I have a problem. It looks like easy but whatever I tried, it doesn't work.

I have two lines like :

```
aaa,bbb,111,22.3,2021-01-01 4:4:4.444

ccc,ddd,555,66.7,2021-02-02 8:8:8.888
```

This regex does what I want : `(.+),(.+),(.+),(.+),(.+)` => 2 matches with 5 groups

```
*Match 0 :*

 group 1 = aaa
 
 group 2 = bbb
 
 ...
 
 group 5 = 2021-01-01 4:4:4.444

*Match 1 :*
 
 group 1 = ccc
 
 ...
```

But if I have more than 5 "fields" it will be complicated. How can I have the same result with something like `(.+),"n repetitions"(.+)`? Or something else ? I tried with `{n}` and `*` but it's not the result expected. I also tried some regex from other posts :

- [Regex to split a CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144431/regex-to-split-a-csv)
- [repeating a section of a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843410/repeating-a-section-of-a-regular-expression)

All the modifications tested don't match with my first simple regex `( *(.+),(.+),(.+),(.+),(.+)* )`

Edit : I'll finally go for a python solution. Thanks you all

Comment: Why not just `str.split` on `','` instead of going the regex route?

Comment: Or use the `csv` module

Comment: @PranavHosangadi i need the regex route version :/ but ty

Comment: If you need regex, then you need to know what the separators are (ok, these are commas), field qualifiers (are they mixed?) and if there are qualifiers, can they be escaped and what with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be to create the regex using `str.join()`.

```
num_cols = 5

re_str = ','.join(['(.+)'] * num_cols)
rexp = re.compile(re_str)

teststr = """aaa,bbb,111,22.3,2021-01-01 4:4:4.444
ccc,ddd,555,66.7,2021-02-02 8:8:8.888"""

re.findall(rexp, teststr)
```

This gives:

```
[('aaa', 'bbb', '111', '22.3', '2021-01-01 4:4:4.444'),
 ('ccc', 'ddd', '555', '66.7', '2021-02-02 8:8:8.888')]
```

You can change num_cols to make your regex match any number of columns in your csv.

Keep in mind that this approach will not account for quotes in the CSV, which are supposed to indicate that the commas within the quote are not column separators. If you want good, easy CSV parsing, just use the `csv` module.

Another caveat is that if your text has more than `num_cols` columns, your matched result will merge them so that you end up with `num_cols` groups per match. For example, if we have six columns in our `teststr` but `num_cols = 5`:

```
teststr =  """aaa,bbb,111,22.3,2021-01-01 4:4:4.444,123
ccc,ddd,555,66.7,2021-02-02 8:8:8.888,456"""
```

the code above gives:

```
[('aaa,bbb', '111', '22.3', '2021-01-01 4:4:4.444', '123'),
 ('ccc,ddd', '555', '66.7', '2021-02-02 8:8:8.888', '456')]
```

Comment: Any solution for a CSV string with `.+` will not work in the long run because `.+` matches any text (but line breaks).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you elaborate on what you mean by "will not work in the long run"? I agree that regex isn't the "correct" way to parse CSVs (just use the `csv` module) but other than the caveats I mentioned in my answer is there something else that could go wrong?

Comment: CSV is a *delimited* text, and `.+` does not care of anything, it grabs everything on its way to the end of a line, so it cannot be used to match delimited texts.

Comment: Wouldn't the fact that greedy match gives back as needed, and that there are more things to match after the greedy quantifier, make it give up everything it's matched until it can get 5 "columns"?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

`([^,]+),?`

It matches any word not containing a comma followed by a comma as many times as you want

Comment: It looks like that i want (sry for my english ^^) but it gives me 9 matches with 1 group and i want 2 matches (for each line) with 5 groups (for each field). I use this https://regexr.com/ to test the regex. Ty for your help.